# How to build a web crawler based on Scrapy to run forever?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to build a web crawler based on Scrapy to grab news pictures from several news portal website. I want to this crawler to be:

1. Run forever

   Means it will periodical re-visit some portal pages to get updates.
2. Schedule priorities.

   Give different priorities to different type of URLs.
3. Multi thread fetch

I've read the Scrapy document but have not found something related to what I listed (maybe I am not careful enough). Is there anyone here know how to do that ? or just give some idea/example about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Scrapy is a framework for the spidering of websites, as such, it is intended to support your criteria but it isn't going to dance for you out of the box; you will probably have to get relatively familiar with the module for some tasks.

1. Running forever is up to your application that calls Scrapy. You tell [the spiders](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/spiders.html) where to go and when to go there.
2. Giving priorities is the job of [Scheduler middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/experimental/scheduler-middleware.html) which you'd have to create and plug into Scrapy. The documentation on this appears spotty and I've not looked at the code - in principle the function is there.
3. Scrapy is inherently, [fundamentally asynchronous](http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/architecture.html#event-driven-networking) which may well be what you are desiring: request B can be satisfied while request A is still outstanding. The underlying connection engine does not prevent you from *bona fide* multi-threading, but Scrapy doesn't provide threading services.

Scrapy is a library, not an application. There is a non-trivial amount of work (code) that a user of the module needs to make.

Comment: Thanks! 
In my understanding, the Spiders seems works for "one time" job (just crawl everything specified and quit). So do you mean if I want a long-running crawler, I should write the application myself and call spider to do the job. It is not easy to implement the long-running logic inside Scrapy by middleware or something else, right?

Comment: You could probably implement re-spider logic in the Spider Middleware layer, but the primitives don't seem well suited for it and my gut feel is that you'd be pushing application layer logic down into the presentation level (if I may be allowed to misuse OSI terminology).

http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/spider-middleware.html

Comment: The scheduler middleware link, which you have provided, is not working now.

Answer (score 0):

About the requirement on running-forever, here's some details.

You need to catch the `signals.spider_idle` signal, and in your method that 
connected to the signal, you need to raise a `DontCloseSpider` exception. The `spider_idle` signal is sent to the scrapy engine when there is no pending requests, and by default the spider will shutdown. You can intercept this process.

See codes blow:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.exceptions import DontCloseSpider
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class FooSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_idle, signals.spider_idle)

    def spider_idle(self):
        #you can revisit your portal urls in this method
        raise DontCloseSpider
```